# "Unable TO Locate adb" android studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, adb

Whenever I run the android emulator, in AVD manager. The message pops "unable to locate adb" however, I have followed all the steps to solve this issue but still getting this error. On other hand, after a while my android emulator loads (virtual android device) and works ok!

Why is this adb un-located pop-up comes?

Comment: did you add the ADB directory to the `environment variables`?

Comment: Install latest "Android SDK platform-tools" in SDK manager>SDK tools, Restart android studio and check again